# MVC 3 Entity Framework - new database column not populating corresponding property

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am creating a web app in MVC 3 using entity framework, and recent spec changes have required I add a new column to one of the database tables (a record creation date).

I have added the new column and populated it with values for my existing records, and updated the model in the entity framework. When I look at the object corresponding to the table with the new column, I can see a property for this new data: however the data for that property is not being retrieved.

Just to clarify:

- I added column "CreatedDate" (datetime) to table "Orders" in my database
- I populated this column with values for my existing records and set it to "not null"
- I updated the model in entity framework
- My model "Order" now has a non-nullable property "CreatedDate"
- I populate a list of orders using LINQ ("from o in DB.Orders select o")
- For any entry on my list, entry.CreatedDate returns "01/01/0001 00:00:00", not the value I have entered into the database.

What's going wrong?

Comment: How did you updated your model? Did you also updated the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

EdmMetadata table?

Do you have an EdmMetadata table in the database?  As far as I know, this table contains a key that is signed by the structure of the database.  So if this value is not changed, the code could not be seeing the change.  Good news is that this table is no longer needed:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<IncludeMetadataConvention>();
```

Comment: I updated the model by the "Update Model from Database" option on the context menu when looking at the edmx file in the model browser.

I can see the "CreatedDate" column on the model broswer and the mapping details shows me that this is mapped to the corresponding database column, and that both are datetime format, but no data is being populated.

I do not have an EdmMetadata table in my database.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed EF code-first.  Have you checked the mapping through all three of the generated files? (ssdl, msl, csdl). Make sure that CreatedDate is mapped back to the ssdl through the msl.  The model browser primary works off the csdl so there could be mapping issue in one of the others.  These should generate into the bin out of the edmx if I remember correctly.

Comment: Figured it - the order records were being returned by stored procedure, not by LINQ directly to the entity framework as I had been led to believe. Thanks to all who helped me figure out where to start looking!